# c# Scintilla убрать пустоты

Tags: c#, scintilla

Как можно убрать пустоты, пример в скринах:

[image: scintilla]

Просто в оригинальном файле их нет, возможно это из за Scintilla. Что нужно использовать?

Comment: Не понятна ситуация без подробностей. Предположу: оригинальный файл создавался в Windows, а затем был открыт в Сайнтилле в каком-нибудь в Линуксе?

Comment: Нет, я сам сижу на Win, Ситуация такова, я из одной программы выстакиваю некий код, сохраняю его в файл, после я должен открыть его в редакторе, который я сделал на C# используя Scintilla.
И вот, когда я открываю, а там эти пробелы, хотя если я открою через другой редактор, тот же Notepad++(который тоже создан на основе Scintilla), то там не таких пробелов.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Хм.. А где раскраска или хотя бы моноширенный шрифт?

Answer (score 1):

Дал некорректный ответ, исправляюсь

Из википедии:

> Отсутствие единого общепринятого представления перевода строки в разных операционных системах осложняет обмен текстовыми данными между ними. Юникод старается примирить эту разницу, уравнивая CR, LF и CR+LF, однако вступает в противоречие с наследуемым им ASCII при трактовке последовательности LF+CR, не предварённой CR: согласно ASCII это один перевод строки, а согласно Юникоду — два.